# Notepad ++ How to remove/replace text in the url

Tags: notepad++, regex, notepad

I've been trying this for an hour and can't seem to get the right regular expression any ideas?

From this:

> https://shopee.co.id/-Full-Version-Mentor-Graphics-QuestaSim-2021.1-Windows-2021.2.1-Linux-Versi-Terbaru-Software-PC-Premium-Full-Version-Terlengkap-Versi-Terbaru-Bergaransi-i.170968774.17485930647?sp_atk=6f57ab89-d722-45ba-8b90-d15a977ee760&xptdk=6f57ab89-d722-45ba-8b90-d15a977ee760

To this:

> https://shopee.co.id/-Full-Version-Mentor-Graphics-QuestaSim-2021.1-Windows-2021.2.1-Linux-Versi-Terbaru-Software-PC-Premium-Full-Version-Terlengkap-Versi-Terbaru-Bergaransi-i.170968774.17485930647

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

- Find what: `\?.*`
- Replace with: Leave empty
- Search mode: Regular expression

**EDIT:** As stated by @phuclv, there is no need to capture the expression as it not used afterwards for replacement. Instead of `(\?.*)`, better use `\?.*`.

Comment: no need to capture anything. Just `\?.*` is enough